# How to display all product reviews on index page

Tags: magento-1.9, review, index

I want to display all approved products reviews programmatically on home page.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this method to retrieved review collection

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('review/review')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()) 
            ->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED)
            ->setDateOrder('desc');
```

in cms home page call your file like this

```
{{block type="core/template" template="namespace/module/filename.phtml"}}
```

you can use this collection directly in phtml file or you can use it via your own block.

Comment: it is not working.what i need to write in "filename.phtml" file.

Comment: Collection code

Comment: I already add these code but not working

Comment: Have you loop through collection data?

Comment: Give me foreach loop code

Comment: Didn't you know how to loop data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41296/discussion-between-darshan-and-mufaddal).